# How do you disable the auto-grow on a material ui select input?

Tags: material-ui

I want the material UI to stay the same width it is before an item is selected. (How the Lab Autocomplete works).

For example if you select the 3rd option here, it will grow, how do I disable that?

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-i4ckf

Instead I would like it to act like the autocomplete does, (Choose Lord of the rings)

https://codesandbox.io/s/kcq04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `minWidth` just set the exact width that you need:

```
formControl: {
  margin: theme.spacing(1),
  width: 120
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've given minWidth property, usually in flex layouts if there's no restriction like maxWidth or flexGrow:0 then it will occupy as much space as available
you can set a fixed width for it like below
also to add text overflow add the necessary css below

```
formControl: {
  margin: theme.spacing(1),
  width: 120,
  // ellipsis overflow
  whiteSpace: "nowrap",
  overflow: "hidden",
  textOverflow: "ellipsis"

}
```

here's the link https://wsh90.csb.app/

**Edit** as pointed by Dekel,
Overflow part is may not be necessary

Comment: There is no reason to add `textOverflow` on the `formControl`, because the relevant part that is overflowing is actually the inner div ( the `div.MuiSelect-select`), which already has the `textOverflow`.

Comment: You can check my answer. The only thing that is needed there is setting the width :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to necrobump this question, but right now I had a similar problem. Since I was using Grid to build my stuff, I could not really just add a fixed width to my input, so as a workaround I did the following:

1. First I added an `id` (or any type of identifier) to my Grid item that is arround the Select

```
<Grid item xs={8} id="framing-grid">
```

2. Then, inside the body of my component, I grabbed my grid item `offsedWidth`

```
const framingGridWidth = document.getElementById('framing-grid')?.offsetWidth;
```

3. Lastly, I gave my Select the "fixed width" that I now got

```
<MySelect
   ...
   sx={{
       width: framingGridWidth
   }}
   ...
/>
```

I've been trying to do something not like this for a while, but it doesn't seem to be going anywhere, so I'll stick to it for now.